# Communication between two angular components

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use data of my children component for my chart in the parent component. In an angular documentation i found a way to solve my problem but it doesn't work. My chart is still empty. Did I miss something in my code or is the technique not working for my special problem? I add some code pieces for represent the problem in a short way.

Child.ts

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output} from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
      selector: 'app-child-component',
      templateUrl: './child.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
    })

export class ResultsStatisticComponent implements OnInit {

        export class ChildCalculateComponent implements OnInit {   
        @Output() public barChartLegend = true;
        @Output() public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
        @Output() public barChartPlugins = [];
    }
```

Parent.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ChildCalculateComponent} from "./child/child.component"

export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    
    @ViewChild(ChildCalculateComponent) childcomponent;
          public barChartLegend;
          public barChartType;
          public barChartPlugins;
        
          ngAfterViewInit(): void {
            this.barChartLegend = this.childcomponent.barChartLegend;
            this.barChartType = this.childcomponent.barChartType;
            this.barChartPlugins = this.childcomponent.barChartPlugins;
          }
```

Comment: you need to provide a selector, not the component class for the ViewChild

Comment: The first line of your code should say implements AfterViewInit.  Also, if you haven't already, have a line of imports with at least:  import {AfterViewInit, Component, Directive, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

Comment: @Katherine I modified my code as you said. The problem still appears. The chart is still empty.

Comment: @Brandon When i change the ViewChild of Parent to: 
 @ViewChild(app-child-component) chartComponent;

Its drops an error: TS2345: Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Function | Type  | InjectionToken '. 

This error is a bit confusing for me because i don't understand why the selector is assigned as a number.

Comment: You should not export a class from within an exported class.

Comment: Selectors are not numbers. See my answer below for an example.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how outputs work.

`@Output()` should be an instance of an `EventEmitter<T>`

Example, not including imports:

```js
// child.component.ts
    
export class ChildComponent {
    
@Output()
  itemWasSelected = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
    
  selectItem(): void {
    this.itemWasSelected.emit(true);
  }
    
}
```

Then, in your parent component, you need to handle the event emitted from the child:

```js
// parent.component.html
    
<app-child (itemWasSelected)="onItemSelected($event)"></app-child>
    
// parent.component.ts
    
export class ParentComponent {
  onItemSelected(itemWasSelected: boolean): void {
    // do something
  }
}
```

If you need to access properties of the child component, or invoke methods on the child, you can use a ViewChild reference. A ViewChild expects a selector to identify it in the parent component's template:

Example:

```js
// parent.component.html
    
<app-child #childComponent></app-child>
    
// parent.component.ts
    
@ViewChild('childComponent')
childComponent: ChildComponent;

doSomething(): void {
  const foo = this.childComponent.foo;
  ...
}
```

Comment: just an FYI, a type is a perfectly valid argument to `ViewChild` as a selector (as in `@ViewChild(ChildCalculateComponent)` will work just fine. it will find the first instance of `ChildCalculateComponent` in the template. see here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2qkemr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Yes, that's correct. A ViewChild will accept a selector, function or ProviderToken. I just chose the string-based example to show the correlation between the component reference in the template and the component class.

Comment: I wasn't sure, as you said in the comments above: "you need to provide a selector, not the component class for the ViewChild" which isn't correct, as the component class is a perfectly valid selector.

Comment: No, you're correct, I mis-spoke in my earlier comment.